# org-mode: any way to automatically collapse "blocks" (e.g., BEGIN_QUOTE)?

Tags: org-mode

When opening an item, any `BEGIN_QUOTE ... END_QUOTE` blocks are automatically expanded.  Is there any way to keep them collapse, and only expand if I consciously TAB on that block?

Ref: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_mono/org.html#Paragraphs

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are in buffer settings for many things like this in org -> https://orgmode.org/manual/In_002dbuffer-settings.html  For code blocks specifically there are these startup options:

> To hide blocks on startup, use these keywords. The corresponding
>   variable is org-hide-block-startup.
>
> ```
> hideblocks   Hide all begin/end blocks on startup 
>
> nohideblocks Do not hide blocks on startup
> ```

If you want that to happen globally just set that variable to true in your config file:

`(setq org-hide-block-startup t)`